# Identify and extract rendered DOM in a web page

Tags: javascript, .net, browser, firefox-addon, html-rendering

I am interested in extracting the text/string literals thats rendered in the web page during a workflow. I want to isolate the strings that are rendered from the ones that are hidden.

My intention is to find the strings which get rendered and map them against each workflow in my application. (I have a way to uniquely identify each string, so thats solved. No worry on that.)

Is there a way i could use preferably .net or in JScript or browser addons or using some trace options in a browser achieve it?

Any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: need to be more specific than just mentioning `strings` or `I have ways to identify string`. Very hard to interpret what you are trying to do. If it is DOM related you will need to use javascript which can do a lot of DOM manipulation

Comment: You need textual content? like <div>this part</div> and then distinguish between visible and non visible like <div style="display:none">non visible text content</div> Would you prefer .net over JavaScript? I think .net has some sort of dom parser from string.

Comment: some html examples would also help a lot

Comment: I am targeting a web page from localization point of view. So i am looking at actual string rendered on the page. I would prefer .net or JS.

Answer (score 0):

How are you pulling the content? One way to only get the visible content is to use Jquery's visible selector. Simply add :visible to your jQuery selector (http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/). For example on this page you could use $('.post-text:visible') to find the question text only if it is visible.